When does a repo on anonymous.4open.science expire?
I read on https://anonymous.4open.science/faq#data:

When a repository is removed or expired only the configuration of the repository is conserved to be able to restore easily the repository and to ensure that no future repository will use the same repository id.

When does a repo on anonymous.4open.science expire? https://anonymous.4open.science/faq doesn't contain the info.

That depends on the repo. The expiry date is defined when creating the repo. By default, the expiry date is 90 days from the current date. The maximum expiry date seems to be ca. 99,913,640 days from the current date.


